# Errors while matching json objects based on similar object values

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, for-loop

In my react app, I have two JSON objects that contain user quiz results. My goal is to generate a percentage value of how many answers each quiz in the roomSurveys has in common with the userSurvey answers using some sort of loop within a loop.

```
  const [userSurvey, setUserSurvey] = useState({ "Q1":"A",
                                                 "Q2":"B, C, A",
                                                 "Q3":"C" });

  const [roomSurveys, setRoomSurveys] = useState({
                                         "user2":{ "Q1":"A",
                                                   "Q2":"B, C, C",
                                                   "Q3":"B" },
                                         "user3":{ "Q1":"C",
                                                   "Q2":"B",
                                                   "Q3":"B" },
                                               });
```

The function that calculates the answers in common would then update a state like this:

```
const [roomMatches, setRoomMatches] = useState({
                                         "user2":{ "percentMatch":"1.0"},
                                         "user3":{ "percentMatch": ".30"}
                                               })
```

here is what I've got so far:

```
      //loop through each user survey in the roomSurvey object
      for (var key of Object.keys(roomSurveys)) {
        var countSame;
        var countTotal;
      //loop through each user survey within the roomSurvey object
        for (var key of Object.keys(roomSurveys[key])) {
          //if answer matches userSurvey answer for the same key,
          //add to count same and count total else, add to count total
          if(roomSurveys[key] == userSurvey[key]){
            countSame++;
            countTotal++;
          }else{
            countTotal++;
          }

          console.log(key + " -> " + roomSurveys[key])
          console.log(key + " -> " + userSurvey[key])
        }
        var percentMatched = countSame/countTotal;
        setRoomMatches([...roomMatches, {key:{['percentMatch']: percentMatched}}]);
      }
```

here are the errors I am getting:

- In the second for loop, the roomSurveys[key] value is always undefined
- roomMatches is not iterable (when trying to add new match percent to roomMatches state)

Comment: Those are just objects, not json.

Answer (score -1):

You have ovewritten your key variable int the second for loop. You need to name them key1 and key2 (or something more verbose)

Answer (score -1):

You're using the same name for `key` variables, rename them and use them as desired.

```js
...               V
      for (var survey of Object.keys(roomSurveys)) {
        var countSame;
        var countTotal;
                   v
        for (var room of Object.keys(roomSurveys[survey])) {
...
```